Share password between app and website with Credential Manager
I have the following error trying to configure credentials sharing
No credential sharing permission was granted from com.casettalab.fidelis to https://auth.fidelisapp.com. Please check that you correctly added asset_statements to your app com.casettalab.fidelis
So when user register within the app the credentials are not associated/shared with my domain auth.fidelisapp.com

Configuration:
I added the metadata within AndroidManifest.xml inside the application tag
<application ... >
        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />

</application>

Here my strings.xml
    <string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">[{ \"include\": \"https://auth.fidelisapp.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json\" }]</string>

My asset link is publicly accessible here the response headers
server: awselb/2.0
date: Sat, 07 Dec 2024 15:43:09 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 436

Robots.txt configuration seems valid and do not block connection to /.well-known/assetlinks.json
The app is published and publicly available.

